# Cos'è un "venturino"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Non sai quanti meschini ci sono ancora su queste colline. Quando giravo con la musica, dappertutto davanti alle cucine si trovava l’idiota, il deficiente, il **venturino**. Figli di alcoolizzati e di serve ignoranti, che li riducono a vivere di torsi di cavolo e di croste. C’era anche chi li scherzava.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è un "venturino"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno 
dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: Essendo Cesare Pavese di origini piemontesi, direi che sta per “ventiȓin” ovvero "trovatello", "orfano" (fonte: https://www.gazzettadalba.it/2017/06/scopriamo-significato-del-termine-piemontese-venti%C8%93in-paolo-tibaldi/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel libro *[Come il letto di un falò: Riflessioni su Cesare Pavese](https://books.google.it/books?id=G7JWAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&lpg=PT72&dq=venturino%20dialetto%20piemontese&source=bl&ots=0zOlLsstLr&sig=ACfU3U3WQ5yKiiXU7k7y44KbS3cCSfiqEQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnlPe66uXhAhUS_aQKHWUPA1EQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=venturino%20dialetto%20piemontese&f=false)* di Franco Lorizio si può leggere una ricerca da parte dell'autore sul termine ***venturino***, proprio sul contesto da te citato:

> Ultimo vocabolo regionale da prendere in considerazione è "**venturino**".
>   "Quando giravo con la musica, dappertutto davanti alle cucine si
>   trovava l'idiota, il deficiente, il venturino." Tale voce è
>   dedotta dal piemontese "***venturin***", "figlio della ventura o della
>   sorte", quindi trovatello.[126]. Il sostantivo nel romanzo pavesiano è
>   rilevabile una sola volta, in quanto l'autore preferisce usare il
>   sinonimo spregiativo "bastardo" (ventidue ricorrenze: dodici al maschile
>   singolare, otto al maschile plurale; due al femminile plurale; in
>   genere il vocabolo è usato come sostantivo), di maggiore effetto
>   espressivo.

Quindi ***venturino*** nel contesto da te citato significa orfano, trovatello.

Il riferimento [126] presente nella citazione offre ulteriori fonti:

- *[Vocabolario piemontese italiano, italiano-piemontese](https://books.google.it/books/about/Vocabolario_piemontese_italiano.html?id=Iig3AAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y)* di Giuseppe Gavuzzi (1891-96)
- *[Dissionari piemontèis](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_itIT819IT819&ei=CNa-XIe5KJKRsAfF-KXYCg&q=dissionari%20piemonteis%20gribaudo&oq=dissionari%20piemonteis%20gribaudo&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7681.11358..11678...2.0..0.334.2259.0j5j5j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j33i160.r80qIjScFPQ)* di Gianfranco Gribaudo (1972-75)
- *[Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_dizionario_della_lingua_italiana)*, fondato da Salvatore Battaglia, direttore scientifico Giorgio Bàrberi Squarotti, Torino, UTET, (1961-2002)

Anche [questo dizionario di Piemontese](http://www.piemunteis.it/dep/dizionario.dep) conferma il significato:

> **ventürin**   - trovatello
>  sostantivo maschile 
>  forme flesse:
>   ventürin, ventürin
>  Fraseologia
>  **ventürin** - trovatello
>   sostantivo maschile

Comment: Grazie, anche io leggendo lo stesso romanzo non trovavo riferimenti e significati per questa parola.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Giuse! Adesso, con il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/) in rete puoi avere accesso al significato di molti termini che prima non si trovavano, come, appunto, quello di [*venturino*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000765.jpg).